# How to randomly draw from a specific role value in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to call all the users in the Discord server and randomly select those users if there is an A Role value.
I need examples like the above or someone to help me.
If you help me once, I'll be grateful.

I used a translator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the `Role.members` attribute

```py
role = ctx.guild.get_role(some_id)
members = role.members
```

To pick a random one:

```py
import random

random.choice(members)
```

Also make sure you have `intents.members` enabled, otherwise it won't work

Reference:

- [Role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Role)

Comment: `random.choice(members)

raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence`

I am getting the above error please help me

Comment: do you have enabled `intents.members`?

Comment: `intents = discord.Intents.all()` I have added intents like this

Comment: in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) too?

Comment: Yes, I also turned on intents on the developer portal

Comment: ok, try printing the `members` variable and send the output

Comment: When members are printed, `[]` is displayed like this.

Comment: so something is wrong with your intents, can't help you unless you post your code somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use `guild.roles` and `Role.members` then choose randomly from them.

```py
@bot.command()
async def random_guy(ctx):

    # This is completely random role
    role = random.choice(ctx.guild.roles)
    # This is a specific role 
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(123456)

    random_member = random.choice(role.members)
    print(random_member, role)
```

Keep in mind you will have to make a check if there are no members with the role.

Comment: `random_member = random.choice(role.members)

raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence`

I am getting the above error please help me